# Battle for Wesnoth: Where did this game originate from?

Tags: ios, battle-for-wesnoth

I installed this game on my iPhone and have been amazed at the amount of playtime I have for one dollar.  What is the background on this game that allows them to have so much content?  I've never heard of it before I downloaded it.

Comment: I know Battle for Wesnoth has been around for at least a few years as a 100% free game on linux... Don't know much beyond that.

Comment: I'll direct you to the Battle for Wesnoth website for more information. http://www.wesnoth.org/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here comes [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Battle_for_Wesnoth) to the rescue!

> The Battle for Wesnoth, or simply
>   Wesnoth, is a turn-based strategy game
>   with a fantasy setting, designed by
>   David White and first released in June
>   2003. In Wesnoth, the player attempts to build a powerful army by
>   controlling villages and defeating
>   enemies for experience. White based
>   Wesnoth loosely on the Sega Genesis
>   games Master of Monsters and Warsong.
>   He wanted to create a
>   freely-available, open source strategy
>   game with very simple rules, but one
>   that had strong artificial
>   intelligence and that was challenging
>   and fun. The Battle for Wesnoth is
>   available without charge for a variety
>   of computer operating systems, and in
>   the iPhone App Store for $4.99. The
>   most current development version of
>   the game, 1.9.3, was released on
>   December 10, 2010. The latest iPhone
>   version was released on May 31,
>   2010. Developed under the GNU General Public License, The Battle for
>   Wesnoth is free software.